# Installing on a Lenovo Thinkpad T43

Tags: system-installation

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad T43 running on Windows XP SP3. I am very much curious with Ubuntu and I would like to try it out. Do I need drivers when I install it? Can I Erase XP and install a fresh OS (ubuntu) without needing drivers?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You can try Ubuntu before installation, since it is on LiveCD. And I think there will not be problems. Anyway, there is hardware support list. You should check it.

Answer (score 1):

Installing Ubuntu in most cases does not require any drivers as Ubuntu comes with open-source drivers for most of the hardware.  So you can install Ubuntu along with your current operating system (dualboot) or erase the current operating system and install Ubuntu.
More instructions on installing are available here:
[1.Ubuntuwiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation)

[2.Ubuntugraphicalinstall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall)